# Laravel 5 shows php file content in browser (doesn't render html)

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, laravel

Laravel 5 site doesn't render html, rather it shows php file content in browser. I tried various apache configurations and changes in htaccess but no luck. Not sure where this is going wrong.

Here is the .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
#RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
#  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

and here is the apache conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/laravelapp/public
ServerName laravelapp.dev
ServerAlias laravelapp.dev
<Directory "/var/www/laravelapp/public">
 AllowOverride all
 Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I'm gonna ask a stupid question: do the have the right file extension? as in `whatever.blade.php`(if you're using blade) or `whatever.html/php` etc.

Comment: yes. They do. @Andrew

Comment: Does the server have php installed?

Comment: Does your Apache configuration have a line like this in it: `AddType application/x-httpd-php .php`

Comment: @JoachimMartinsen Nope.

Comment: Google how to setup PHP with Apache and your system, and fix whatever is missing. Probably a few steps to do.

Comment: @JoachimMartinsen I just added that line and now it downloads the php file. I am gonna try php setup with apache.

Comment: Yeah, you want to add something like this aswell: `Action application/x-httpd-php "/path/to/php"`

Comment: @JoachimMartinsen : Invalid command 'Action', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Action 'configtest' failed.

Comment: Which Operating System ? After installing php, did you enable it with a command like `a2enmod php5` (This is the command on Debian based distros) ?

Comment: @Zimmi Its Ubuntu. I just hit "a2enmod php5" and it says ERROR: Module php5 does not exist! -_- ...

Comment: http://digitizor.com/2012/09/03/how-to-fix-module-php5-does-not-exist-error-in-apache-linux/ this helped. and plus sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5